# Is there a basic sample DLL build for a jagamp:gluegen dll out there?

Tags: java, c, jogl

I am working on a system where I am using part of the JOGL OpenGL bindings to Java.  I find the basic idea behing the "gluegen" C to Java binding generator good but the docs are thin and I havn't been able to locate a simple sample of gluegen usage consisting of:

- A C module the does something like modify a string or print a string to stdout (ie: easily tested from java code) an expanded version one with multiple methods that handle each data type handled by gluegen.
- the appropriate "cfg", ".h" files needed to power gluegen for the sample source.
- A build script - ideally simple not factored out too much into an endless chain to follow generic makefile or shell script :)
- the result of running the build script gives you the generated and sample code for a complete native side DLL with DLL main, export tables, and whatever else is needed to load into java on a windows box (.lib for unix)
- A C compile of the code with MSVC and/or GCC to compile and link the code and generated code to produce the DLL.
- The generated java class or classes that mate with the DLL including initialization.

In a sense sort of a "hello world" in C to be called from Java as a place to start.

PK

Comment: You have almost certainly seen these?  ***[LOGL Demos](http://jogamp.org/jogl-demos/www/)***, ***[gluegen simplest possible example](http://jogamp.org/gluegen/doc/manual/#SecSimplest)***, and ***[gluegen string handling](http://jogamp.org/gluegen/doc/manual/#SecString)***.  All from the same main site, but do seem to address a couple of your line items.

Comment: yes I have. I downloaded the source have built it, and run the jogl test suite.  They have samples of using gluegen to do part of the process.  But it does not have a good explanation of how to structure a build to get from code (c cfg and headers) to a finished DLL and what complications - generation of export tables, how dll main is created, for GCC and VC etc etc. a sample "hello world" that has a generated DLL build, generated java classes, and a java "main" that calls the DLL to print "hello world" would be a great to have, highly informative and save a lot of time :)

Comment: We don't support Visual Studio, please use GCC. Please read carefully the simplest possible example as ryyker suggested, it already answers some of your questions.